# Create up to date copy of another table with altered columns, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a PostgreSQL table (shown below) that is currently ~150 gigabytes. 90+ gigabytes of the storage is used by the json `data` column (about 222 bytes per entry, millions of rows). The goal is to perform analysis on the sequence of accelerometer values for each `device_id`, something that requires an export. Current exports and queries are slow, so I would like to create a reduced size live copy of the table.

I would like to create a reduced size table by converting the `data` column to three float columns (`float_x`, `float_y`, `float_z`), which should reduce the storage used by approximately 90%. I cannot change the query that inserts into the `accelerometer` table, so I would like to create a second table, `accelerometer_optimized`, identical to `accelerometer`, but with the three float columns instead of the json column. Is there a way to create `accelerometer_optimized` that keeps it permanently up to date with `accelerometer`? I am aware of generated columns, but my goal here is to have a separate table so that sequential scans are fast and exports to CSV are fast. I would imagine that this would look like a "generated table", but I am not sure of the right way to approach this. I looked into materialized views, but that did not seem like the correct path either. Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide. Thank you for your time.

```
                                                                                Table "public.accelerometer"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                                     Default                                     | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 _id          | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('accelerometer__id_seq'::regclass)                                      | plain    |              | 
 timestamp    | double precision            |           | not null |                                                                                 | plain    |              | 
 device_id    | character varying(128)      |           | not null |                                                                                 | extended |              | 
 data         | json                        |           | not null |                                                                                 | extended |              | 
 pg_timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           |          | generated always as (to_timestamp("timestamp" / 1000::double precision)) stored | plain    |              |
```

Comment: Have only one table `accelerometer_optimized` and turn `accelerometer` into a view. Define an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view that extracts the JSON attributes and insertes them properly.

Comment: (Original poster, but I lost my login) Laurenz's suggestion is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!